# Python Requests json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data for valid json

Tags: python, json

I have a pandas data frame that I am converting to a list of dicts, and then trying to send those to an API using the request module. A sample of the json:

```
[{
    "street": "43 street road",
    "secondary": "",
    "city": "city",
    "state": "st",
    "zipcode": "12345",
    "match": "invalid",
    "candidates": "1"
}, {
    "street": "65 road ave",
    "secondary": "",
    "city": "city",
    "state": "st",
    "zipcode": "12345",
    "match": "invalid",
    "candidates": "1"
}, {
    "street": "123 road street",
    "secondary": "815",
    "city": "city",
    "state": "st",
    "zipcode": "12345",
    "match": "invalid",
    "candidates": "1"
}]
```

and here is the code I am trying to use to send it to the API

```
import requests

auth_id = 'id'
auth_token = 'token'
url = f'https://us-street.api.smartystreets.com/street-address?auth-id={auth_id}&auth-token={auth_token}'

some_pd_addresses = pd.DataFrame(some_file_path)

dict_addresses = some_pd_addresses.to_dict(orient='records')

Headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, json = json.dumps(dict_addresses[1:11]), headers=Headers)
```

When I execute this code, I get the error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)` even though I can run this JSON through a Linter to confirm that it is a valid JSON. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is it just me of `dict_addresses[1:11]` should be `dict_addresses.items()[1:11]` ?

Comment: Json argument expects a dict which is automatically converted to json, but you are passing a json directly

Comment: @FrédéricPerron it is a list of dictionaries, not one dict

Comment: @PabloHenkowski if I pass the list of dicts, I still get the same error

Comment: Yes, clear. A list is not a dict. I can only speculate that either the API is expecting only a single address or that you have to wrap the list into a dict

Comment: from the docs, i think you want data = dict_addresses[1:11] instead of using json. and verify your headers are correct based based on the docs. https://www.smartystreets.com/docs/cloud/us-street-api#http-request-url